# ngModel in custom component work one way only

Tags: javascript, angular

Lets say I have a component

```
const DEFAULT_VALUE_ACCESSOR = CONST_EXPR(new Provider(
NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComp), multi: true}));

@Component({
 selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
     <another-one></another-one>  
  `,
  providers: [DEFAULT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
```

and now when I use the component like:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app',
 template: `<my-comp [(ngModel)]="someValue"></my-comp>
         <input [(ngModel)]="someValue" />`
})
class App {
   someValue: number = 5 
}
```

The value is passed to the `<my-comp>` component, however after that when the value is changed inside the input, the `ngModel` is updated, but not the `<my-comp>`. Is there something else that I need to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you need to explicitly call the `onChange` callback that is registered by Angular2:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class MyComp implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    (...)
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

For example when you consider that the state of this custom component changes. Here is a sample on a click:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div (click)="updateState()">Update state</div>
  `
})
export class MyComp implements ControlValueAccessor {

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.internalState = value;
  }

  updateState() {
    this.internalState = 'new state';
    this.onChange(this.internalState);
  }
}
```

This article could give you more hints (see section "NgModel-compatible component"):

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges()` is called when `@Input()`s values change:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
     <another-one></another-one>  
  `
})
class MyComp {
  @Input() someField:number;

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log(changes);
  }
}
```

and now when I use the component like:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app',
 template: `<my-comp [someField]="someValue"></my-comp>
         <input [(ngModel)]="someValue" />`
})
class App {
   someValue: number = 5 
}
```

Comment: ok, but still when ngModel is changed from the input what will notify me in the <my-comp> that the value is changed? I want to use ngModel and not someField

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="someValue"` changes `someValue` in `App`. Angular change detection passes the new value to `someField` in `MyComp` because of `[someField]="someValue"`. Every time `someValue` changes, Angular updates `someField` and every time `someField` is changed by Angular, `ngOnChanges(...)` is called.